# Prevent users from sending windows(xterm, gvim, ..) to my VNC display

Tags: linux, x11, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

VNC allows any user to send their windows like `xterm, gvim`, .. to any other user's VNC, using -display option of command or by setting my VNC display in DISPLAY variable.

Some users exploiting this feature and keep on sending `xterms` to my VNC.
Is there any way where I can completely disable or selective allow other users?

My viewer details:

```
VNC Viewer 5.2.1 (r5668) 32-bit(Aug 18 2014 12:58:45) from RealVNC
```

I am looking for some options provided by this viewer/other to achieve this

Comment: That has nothing to do with VNC. It's how X11 works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Voting to move.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it's not related to programming. Please move it to correct StackExchange

Comment: The command you're looking for is `xhost`.  Read the manual page to understand how it works.  It (dis)allows users or hosts to connect to your display.

Comment: @mrjink Yes. When I do `xhost -`. Other users unable to send `xterm` to my VNC. Please post as an answer & elaborate on allowing other users selectively.

Comment: @BhargavKatkam I posted my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42130755/2020834

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're looking for is [`xhost`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xhost.1.xhtml).  `xhost` allows you to control access to your X environment and `$DISPLAY`.
In your case, the default is probably "no access control" or `xhost +`.

By specifying `xhost -` you will disallow everyone (excluding yourself) access to your current `$DISPLAY`.  Other users won't be able to run commands on your `$DISPLAY` anymore.

You can selectively add (or remove) users and/or machines from the access list, with `xhost +si:localuser:username` or `xhost +otherhost`.  For more information on the `si:` syntax, please see [the Xsecurity manual](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man7/Xsecurity.7.xhtml).

Comment: Though I have added `xhost +si:localuser:<user>`. `<user>` is unable to send `xterm` to my display. But if I add `xhost <host>`, `<user>` can send now

Comment: Is there any other way to allow users selectively?

Also, where does `xhost` store these entries?